# How to use async within a lambda which returns a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asynchronous, lambda

I have a method which is Async "upstream". I'm trying to follow best practice and go all-in qith async all the way up the stack.

Within a Controller action within MVC I predictably hit the deadlock issue If I rely on .Result().

Changing the Controller action to async seems to be the way to go, though the issue is that the async method is called multiple times within a lambda.

How can I await on a lamda *that returns multiple results*?

```
public async Task<JsonResult>  GetLotsOfStuff()
{
    IEnumerable<ThingDetail> things=  previouslyInitialisedCollection
                                      .Select(async q => await GetDetailAboutTheThing(q.Id)));
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

You can see I have tried making the lambda async, but this just gives a compiler exception:

Cannot convert source type

> > `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ThingDetail>` to target type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ThingDetail>`

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: now your select return enumeration with task, but you try assign it to enumeration with ThingDetail, as vatiant you can use `var` keyword instead declare type directly like: `var things=...` instead of `IEnumerable<ThingDetail> things = ...`

Comment: `result` isn't defined in the code block. Presumably, you meant it to be `return Json(things, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- Convert your collection of `Thing`s into a collection of `Task<Thing>`s.
- Then join all those tasks using `Task.WhenAll` and await it.
- Awaiting the joint task will give you a `Thing[]`

```
public async Task<JsonResult>  GetLotsOfStuff()
{
    IEnumerable<Task<ThingDetail>> tasks = collection.Select(q => GetDetailAboutTheThing(q.Id));

    Task<int[]> jointTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    IEnumerable<ThingDetail> things = await jointTask;

    return Json(things, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or, succinctly and using type inference:

```
public async Task<JsonResult>  GetLotsOfStuff()
{
    var tasks = collection.Select(q => GetDetailAboutTheThing(q.Id));
    var things = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return Json(things, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/78ApTI

Note: since `GetDetailAboutTheThing` seems to return a `Task<Thing>`, the convention is to append `Async` to its name - `GetDetailAboutTheThingAsync`.

Comment: "That's the way to do it". Excellent, thanks. I had tried the WhenAll method but obviously had missed an interim step.

I take your point about the Async method naming convention and I do agree. I'll implement this.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line in both code blocks be `return Json(things, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`? `result` doesn't appear to be defined in either code block.

Comment: @M.Babcock Correct, it's fixed now. Thanks

Comment: This method is an anti pattern. The reason in that you don't know how much items in a collection. It can overload ThreadPool. In this case you should use TPL or split items on small blocks and WaitAll in a loop limited number of tasks.